# Restrict API data to first 100 results

Tags: python, api

I am trying to pull some data from The Movie Database API using Python. My goal is to grab the top 100 revenue movies for a given year. So far, I've been able to get all movies for a given year, sorted by revenue. I want to restrict to the first 100 so as to not have too much data:

```
import requests

url = 
'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key={apikey}&sort_by=revenue.desc&page=1&primary_release_year=2012'

payload = "{}"
response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: If you want to ask the API to only return the top 100, then you'll need to read their documentation, they may have an option for it. But also, they may not. If what you want instead is to take the results, and only look at the first 100, it depends on how their response is formatted.

Comment: Most of the API, providing pagination, you have to check, this api provide pagination or not.